# Vivado simulation ip_user_files/ipstatic filename conflicts

Tags: simulation, vivado

When integrating IPs in Vivado apparently some files are being copied to a `ip_user_files/ipstatic` directory. If two IPs happen to have the same filename, only one gets placed there, and then I see errors caused by one IP being compiled with another's sub-modules.

Is there a way to force Vivado to compile each IP separately with its own files?

Note: I've also posted this question on Xilinx Vivado forums with a [minimal example](https://forums.xilinx.com/t5/Design-Entry/ip-user-files-ipstatic-filename-conflicts/m-p/787493#M14209).

Comment: You'll have to be more specific about what errors you're getting. In general, the ipstatic area holds sub-modules that are common to all Xilinx IP. Even if different IPs put things in there, they should in fact be the same identical sub-modules. With user IP, it's up to you to make sure that incompatible modules don't have the same name, but I agree that it's probably a bug that they aren't placed into separate subdirectories to begin with.

Comment: I think the specific errors I'm seeing are less interesting because they just say that one module tries to use another module but the input and output signals do not match. Are you saying this `ipstatic` directory is specific to Xilinx IP? If I change the vendor name of my IP from the default "xilinx.com" do you think it will help?

Comment: No, I checked and its not just for IP marked with vendor "xilinx.com".

Comment: I found a workaround: using `config_rtl -prefix <prefix>` in HLS can add a custom prefix for every generated module, thus solving the conflicts. I still hope there's a better solution in Vivado itself though.